# In UWP, RichEditBox is loading .rtf as source code instead of interpreting it

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm use RichEditBox's LoadFromStream() method to retrieve my document, but the data that gets put into the editor is .rtf source. I set the format to Rtf so that isn't the issue. I keep getting this:

```
{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ .....
```

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`LoadFromStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.itextdocument.loadfromstream) method should work well with correct `.rtf` format document. Since you didn't provide any code snippet, here is my simple code that can retrieve the document correctly:

```
<RichEditBox x:Name="Richbox"  Height="400" Margin="40" ></RichEditBox>
<Button x:Name="Loadfile" Content="Load File" Click="Loadfile_Click"></Button>
```

Code behind

```
private async void Loadfile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{  
    StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/test1.rtf")); 
    IRandomAccessStream randAccStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    Richbox.Document.LoadFromStream(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, randAccStream);
}
```

If nothing wrong with the code itself, then you may need to check the `RTF` specification if the document is in correct [Rich Text Format (RTF)](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm). The document with suffix `.rtf` may not sure with correct `RTF` format. You may try to use a verify tool or just word to check if your document can show correctly.

[Here](https://github.com/sunteenwu/CRichEditBox/blob/master/CCleanRich/CCleanRich/Assets/test1.rtf) is my `RTF` file I tested that can work well, you could use for testing to narrow your issues, also this project is a completed demo that can work well. If you still have issues please upload a minimal reproduced project.